# Open new link in existing browser keeping master page displayed

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a default site created when I started a new project. It also created a master page that uses an `Menu` control for navigation.

I am trying to add a link to an external forum, and I want to embed the forum in one of my content pages. I've tried setting the `Target` of the `MenuItem`, but no luck.

Any ideas  or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: So you want the other site to display inside of your site?

Comment: Yes.  I've tried using IFrame like answer below suggested but it still does not appear inside of my site.

I have <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://localhost:83" Target="MainFrame" Text="Forum"/>
in my asp:Menu.

Inside my ContentPlaceHolder where I want the forum page to appear, I have 
<iframe id="MainFrame" name="MainFrame" width="900" runat="server"></iframe>

It still opens a new window though.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I would think you are stuck with using an IFrame